# Sql server session mode in asp.net web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two project solutions. First one is with asp.net (.aspx) web application. The second one is mvc (.cshtml) web application.The first application has a redirect link to second application. The user logins only through the first application. I want to store the user login details and page details of the user in sqlserver using sql server session mode.
Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks

**EDIT**
I tried using the sql server session mode from the [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net).
The session values are stored in the ASPState database.How to check the session is expired and the values are not used from the expired session. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code checks for the session expiry.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Context.Session != null)
        {
            if (Session.IsNewSession)
            {
                HttpCookie newSessionIdCookie = Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"];
                if (newSessionIdCookie != null)
                {
                    string newSessionIdCookieValue = newSessionIdCookie.Value;
                    if (newSessionIdCookieValue != string.Empty)
                    {
                        // This means Session was timed Out and New Session was started
                        // Do whatever you want
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```